# How to calculate sum of time span in day with similar time span

Tags: c#

I have a number of "from time" and "to time" in a date.

For example:

```
from time    | - to Time -     |---- Date ---- | -- diff date -- 
 -- 10:00 -- |   -- 12:00 --   |  2019-08-07   |      2 Hours
 -- 10:00 -- |   -- 12:00 --   |  2019-08-07   |      2 Hours
 -- 11:00 -- |   -- 12:00 --   |  2019-08-07   |      1 Hours
 -- 11:00 -- |   -- 14:00 --   |  2019-08-07   |      3 Hours
 -- 14:00 -- |   -- 18:00 --   |  2019-08-07   |      4 Hours
 -- 15:00 -- |   -- 17:00 --   |  2019-08-07   |      2 Hours
 -- 18:00 -- |   -- 19:00 --   |  2019-08-07   |      1 Hours
```

Sum of the times above is: 15 Hours

But its wrong. because Some times are repetitive. Correct answer is 9 Hours.

How I can calculate Correct answer in this question?

Comment: As @TimSchmelter is alluding too, what is the structure of the data?

Comment: If you have the data in a list, I suggest using the NuGet package `Itenso.TimePeriod`.

Comment: Do you need to calculate this in C# or in SQL? Is data saved as a list of objects or is it dataTable or something else?

Comment: just remove duplicates, and calculate. Most important thing is it SQL table ? Array ? List of objects ?

Comment: its list of data from database ( sql server )  . and i want calculate with c# or linq

Comment: all of data is not duplicate . some times is common part . ex : 10-12 and 11-13

Comment: What if the next record is different date? Do you need to calculate time span for each day separately or complete time span?

Comment: @Matt  yes i want to calculate every day separately . so if the next record is diffrent date i must be calculate just times of that date ...

Comment: @TimSchmelter  they are datetimes . its just example To convey the concept of the question

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, it should work and it is very simple to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is harder than you might think, at least for the general case.

Here's a modified version of a class that I use for calculating ranges of numbers, accounting for overlapping regions (the full class also handles excluded regions, which I have included but am not using for this answer):

```
public sealed class RangeCombiner
{
    public void Include(long start, long end)
    {
        _boundaries.Add(new Boundary(start, isStart: true, isIncluded: true));
        _boundaries.Add(new Boundary(end, isStart: false, isIncluded: true));

        _sorted = false;
    }

    public void Exclude(long start, long end)
    {
        _boundaries.Add(new Boundary(start, isStart: true, isIncluded: false));
        _boundaries.Add(new Boundary(end, isStart: false, isIncluded: false));

        _sorted = false;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _boundaries.Clear();
    }

    public long TotalIncludedRange()
    {
        sortIfNecessary();

        return totalIncludedRange();
    }

    void sortIfNecessary()
    {
        if (_sorted)
            return;

        _boundaries.Sort();
        _sorted = true;
    }

    long totalIncludedRange()
    {
        int  included = 0;
        int  excluded = 0;
        long start    = 0;
        long total    = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _boundaries.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (_boundaries[i].IsStart)     // Starting a region...
            {
                if (_boundaries[i].IsIncluded)      // Starting an included region...
                {
                    if (++included == 1 && excluded == 0)       // Starting a new included region,
                        start = _boundaries[i].Value;            // so remember its start time.
                }
                else                                // Starting an excluded region...
                {
                    if (++excluded == 1 && included > 0)        // Ending an included region,
                        total += _boundaries[i].Value - start;   // so add its range to the total.
                }
            }
            else                            // Ending a region...
            {
                if (_boundaries[i].IsIncluded)      // Ending an included region...
                {
                    if (--included == 0 && excluded == 0)       // Ending an included region,
                        total += _boundaries[i].Value - start;   // so add its range to the total.
                }
                else                                // Ending an excluded region...
                {
                    if (--excluded == 0 && included > 0)        // Starting an included region,
                        start = _boundaries[i].Value;            // so remember its start time.
                }
            }
        }

        return total;
    }

    readonly List<Boundary> _boundaries = new List<Boundary>();

    bool _sorted;

    struct Boundary : IComparable<Boundary>
    {
        public Boundary(long value, bool isStart, bool isIncluded)
        {
            Value      = value;
            IsStart    = isStart;
            IsIncluded = isIncluded;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Boundary other)
        {
            if (this.Value < other.Value)
                return -1;

            if (this.Value > other.Value)
                return 1;

            if (this.IsStart == other.IsStart)
                return 0;

            if (this.IsStart)
                return -1;

            return 1;
        }

        public readonly long Value;
        public readonly bool IsStart;
        public readonly bool IsIncluded;
    }
}
```

And here's how you use that for your problem. Note how I convert `DateTime` values into tick counts for the regions:

The output of the following code is `Total = 09:00:00`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var combiner = new RangeCombiner();

        var from1 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 10, 00, 00);
        var to1   = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 12, 00, 00);
        var from2 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 10, 00, 00);
        var to2   = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 12, 00, 00);
        var from3 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 11, 00, 00);
        var to3   = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 12, 00, 00);
        var from4 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 11, 00, 00);
        var to4   = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 14, 00, 00);
        var from5 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 14, 00, 00);
        var to5   = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 18, 00, 00);
        var from6 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 15, 00, 00);
        var to6   = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 17, 00, 00);
        var from7 = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 18, 00, 00);
        var to7   = new DateTime(2019, 08, 07, 19, 00, 00);

        combiner.Include(from1.Ticks, to1.Ticks);
        combiner.Include(from2.Ticks, to2.Ticks);
        combiner.Include(from3.Ticks, to3.Ticks);
        combiner.Include(from4.Ticks, to4.Ticks);
        combiner.Include(from5.Ticks, to5.Ticks);
        combiner.Include(from6.Ticks, to6.Ticks);
        combiner.Include(from7.Ticks, to7.Ticks);

        Console.WriteLine("Total = " + TimeSpan.FromTicks(combiner.TotalIncludedRange()));
    }
}
```

COMPLEXITY:

- Adding the data is an O(N) operation
- Calculating the total non-overlapping non-excluded is an O(N.Log(N))
  operation.
- Therefore adding *and* calculating is also O(N.Log(N)) overall.

Comment: its Work My friend . and thank you very very very much .

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm with LINQ in mind (Note that I do not write C#):

1. Have a class with fields: totime, fromtime, date, computed field for difference.
2. implement equals and hash methods for this class
3. transform the collection from DB to Set using LINQ. - `HashSet<T> foo = new HashSet<T>(from x in bar.Items select x)`;
4. Transform Set back to list.
5. do a Aggregate with the differences to a sum.

Without LINQ things would be easier IMO.

Comment: thank . do you have sample for this method ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/myhStL

This will give you a list of total hours for each different day.

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>(){
    new DateTime(2019,1,1,10,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,1,12,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,1,13,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,1,14,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,2,10,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,2,12,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,2,14,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,3,10,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,3,11,0,0),
    new DateTime(2019,1,3,12,0,0)
   };


  var result = dates
    .OrderBy(d => d.Date)
    .ThenBy(d => d.TimeOfDay)
    .GroupBy(d => d.Date)
    .Select(bla => new
    {
      Date = bla.First().Date,
      Hours = bla.Last() - bla.First()
    }).ToList();
```

Result:

> Date: 1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM Hours: 04:00:00
>   Date: 1/2/2019 12:00:00 AM Hours: 04:00:00
>   Date: 1/3/2019 12:00:00 AM Hours: 02:00:00

Comment: This only works if there are no gaps and even then you'd still need to deal with the earliest start time and the latest end time unless you just merged both into one list.

Comment: I edited the answer, I think it should be fine now.

Comment: thank u very much . but It's a bit different to what I wanted .